# Удалить сообщение если там будет одно, или несколько слов из перечня

Tags: python, telebot

Сделал телеграм-бота. Как сделать так, чтобы он удалял сообщение, если там будет мат. Как поместить в одну команду проверки несколько слов?

Я не могу сделать так чтобы он удалял несколько слов, типа 'hello' и 'LOL'

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def filter(message):
    if 'hello' in message.text:
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 2):

При помощи функции [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```py
message.text = "..." # текст сообщения
curses = ["one", "two", "three"] # перечень слов

if any(c in message.text for c in curses):
```

Comment: у вас нет опечатки ? txt и text

Comment: @Интик спасибо, исправил